# Gotchas when building a Beowulf Cluster

Tags: cluster

I am creating a beowulf cluster on a very limited budget which will be used to simulate fluid flow problems. I have never created a beowulf cluster before and am looking for suggestions and gotchas that I will run into.

Comment: Do people even call them 'beowulf' clusters any more? I thought they're just 'clusters' now.

Comment: it seems to me that there are better ways of solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

Hardware fails.  You'll have to keep fixing it or replacing it, so make sure you have an *easy* way to handle it.  I built a cluster using FAI to autodeploy the nodes so that if one failed for any reason (disk, CPU, whatever), it was easy to rebuild a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never done it before, building a Rocks cluster the first time can save you a lot of time and frustration, as well as teach you what you need to know if you want to "roll your own" the next time around.

http://www.rocksclusters.org/wordpress/